# sortedArrayUsingComparator in sorting array contains object with 2 numbers

Tags: ios

iam trying to sort a object with 2 numbers using the api sortedArrayUsingComparator

```
array1= [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    person *p1 = (person*)obj1;
    person *p2 = (person*)obj2;

    if (p1.value>p2.value && p1.age>p2.age)
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

i want to make code to sort something like this ,,,,

```
input : 0  1
        1  2
        0  9
        1  4
        2  3

output: 0  1
        0  9
        1  2
        1  4 
        2  3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Please don't cast `id` to `person *`. The type `id` is implicitly compatible with any Objective-C object type, so the cast is useless and it only decreases readability.
2. Also, class names should begin with a capital letter. Better name your class `Person`, not `person`.
3. The actual problem is somewhat similar to lexicographic sorting:

---

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id lhs, id rhs) {
    Person *p1 = lhs, *p2 = rhs;

    if (p1.value > p2.value) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (p1.value < p2.value) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        if (p1.age > p2.age)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (p1.age < p2.age)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Comment: 1. Please don't use the comma operator *ever*.

Comment: 2. Using proper parameter types for the block removes need for secondary variables altogether.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe 1. I haven't used the comma operator anywhere. 2. But then the block wouldn't be of a compatible type. (Try it, you will get a compiler error.) I'd prefer that *if it was legal.* 3. Thanks.

Comment: 1. OK, wrong term, you can keep your *declaration separator*. 2. The block would be of compatible type (no compiler warning in current clang when using `(Person *lhs, Person *rhs)`, with `-Weverything`).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe 1. Thanks! 2. So rather *I* should try it. (And GCC was wrong then. Would you happen to know if the C rule for compatible function types does *not* apply to blocks? It seems so...)

Comment: Yes, I do remember I read something about the thinking behind and how block types are tested for compatibility (extenting C's compatible-type system) but I cannot find it any more.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend sorting with [NSSortDescriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSArray *sortdesc = @[
                      [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES],
                      [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES]
                     ];
NSLog(@"%@", [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdesc]);
```